# Pointer type without delete operator

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Is it possible to construct a pointer type that acts and behaves (in terms of syntax) like a normal pointer, except that you can't call delete on it (perhaps with preprocessor macros)?

Example usage:

```
borrowed_ptr<int> ptr = new int[42]; 

ptr[12] = 1;
cout<<ptr[12]<<endl; //prints 1

delete ptr; //error: no operator delete for borrowed_ptr<int>

borrowed_ptr<int> ptr2 = new int(2);
delete ptr2; //error
```

Also this should work too

```
template<typename t>
void func(borrowed_ptr<t> *arg)
{
   delete arg; //error
}

//somewhere else
int *t = new *int;
func(t);
```

However, "reverse assignement" shouldn't work.

```
borrowed_ptr<int> foo = new int(2);
int* bar = foo; //error
```

Whether or not the * is required when declaring a borrowed_ptr doesn't matter to me. It's just important that code like

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T* whatever)
{
    //do something with whatever
   delete whatever; 
}

template <typename T>
void bar(T* whatever)
{
    //do something with whatever
}
```

can be called with this borrowed_ptr like this:

```
borrowed_ptr<int> a = new int(2);
foo(a); //error, function tries to delete
bar(a); //fine, and has the same semantics as handing over a raw int*
```

Note: i don't want the data deleted when the pointer type is delete itself. it should just be a borrowed ptr that can not be deleted because it belongs to someone else.

Comment: Just use the appropriate container/smart pointer.

Comment: I don't want the stuff deleted. unique_ptr and shared_ptr delete the underlying data once they go out of scope/the ref counts are 0.

Comment: Just ban the use of `delete` from your codebase, and a simple `grep` can serve as your police :-)

Comment: @TravisG Why no deleting? Do you realize that it's undefined behavior to not call `delete` before program ends?

Comment: @TravisG, Then how are you going to use it? You'll have data lingering after it goes out of scope with no way to access it.

Comment: It would be syntactic sugar to make more code readable in cases where shared pointers are not allowed (for performance reasons? no c++11? no boost? your framework programmer was too lazy yet to program shared ptr himself?). You see a borrowed_ptr<t> and you know: this belongs to someone else.

Comment: @TravisG: are you looking for something like [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3514.pdf) for "The World's Dumbest Smart Pointer?"

Comment: @Pubby: It's not undefined behavior, it's just a leak. It's a practical concern, not a language concern.

Comment: @TravisG: Surely if we have `borrowed_ptr<t>` modeling a pointer, we should no longer have a pointer to *that*?

Comment: @GManNickG, yes, that was just to indicate that it's "just a pointer without delete"

Comment: To everyone, I updated the question to have more detail.

Answer (score 0):

see various implementations of smart pointers in C++ on google. Plenty of good examples available.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you really wany is [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: `shared_ptr` does not provide an overload of `operator []`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `unique_ptr` for that purpose:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[10]);
```

No need to call `delete[]`, impossible to invoke `delete` (no implicit conversion to the encapsulated pointer type) and an overload of the subscript operator is provided:

```
cout << ptr[1];
```

Comment: @Pubby: true, but you have to make some effort to achieve that, you can't do it by mistake. Neither `delete ptr` nor `delete[] ptr` will work

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` operator requires a built-in pointer type, so *any* smart pointer would do the trick.  Most of the usual ones have some additional functionality, which you may or may not want; if necessary, it's not difficult to write your own; just wrap the pointer in a class which provides an overload for the operators unary `*` and `->`.  Templated pseud-copy constructors and assignment operators can provide for the implicit type conversions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can use `std::unique_ptr`. Don't forget to include `<memory>` for this:

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
   std::unique_ptr<int[]> a(new int[2] {1, 2, ...});

   a[1]; // 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the problems derive from an improper use of therminology: **you don't delete pointers, you delete what they point-to.**

At this point, you need an object that mimics a pointer, hence, as far as I can see, your first line should be

```
borrowed_ptr<int> ptr = new int[42];
```

and not `borrowed_ptr<int> *ptr = new int[42];`. That makes `ptr` to be an "on stack object", for which no delete can be called.

For `borrowed_ptr`

```
template<class T>
class borrowed_ptr
{
public:
    borrowed_ptr() :p() {}
    explicit borrowed_ptr(T* p_) :p(p_) {}

    T* operator->() const { return p; } //don't include this operator if just want an array-like behavior
    T& operator*() const { return *p; } p; } //don't include this operator if just want an array-like behavior
    T& operator[](int x) const { return p[x]; }

private:
    T* p; //< here is where pointer lives
};
```

is all that is required.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a non-owning "smart" pointer with no reference counting, and that allows pointer arithmetic.

There is no such type in the standard library, as of C++17. The closest equivalent<sup>1</sup> is the proposed<sup>2</sup> [`std::experimental::observer_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr), however it disallows pointer arithmetic by design, for the same reason that you desire to disallow "delete": it is error-prone. The only other non-owning smart pointer in the standard library is [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), although it performs reference counting and requires the owner(s) to use [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to manage its lifetime, and does not allow pointer arithmetic either.

You'd have to implement it yourself, fortunately this is quite simple. You can start with an [implementation](https://github.com/martinmoene/observer-ptr/blob/master/include/nonstd/observer_ptr.h) of `observer_ptr`, and add an overload for `operator[]` and other arithmetic operators.

However, note that it is generally considered better practice, or more "idiomatic C++", to simply raw pointers (or references) for non-owning pointers to resources. See for instance the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r-resource-management) on resource management. This keeps it simple, avoids code clutter, and increases interoperability (like constness, smart pointers tend to "infect" other parts of the code). Raw pointers are indeed somewhat error-prone, but most mistakes can be caught via static code analysis. That being said, I agree that non-owning smart pointers have their use cases, when used appropriately.

<sup>1</sup> So close that in fact, some people advocate renaming it `borrowed_ptr` in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/80xm9g/stdobserver_ptr_should_be_renamed_stdptr/)

<sup>2</sup> See proposal [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4282.pdf)